# How to backup all the data of my Ubuntu system?

Tags: backup, remastersys

I am currently using the `remastersys` to backup my Ubuntu system, but at the end it tells me the following error:

```
The compressed filesystem is larger than genisoimage allows for a single file. You must try to reduce the amount of data you are backing up and try again.
```

But, the free space left 2GB after the backup the system. I have no ideas to fix this problem. (In addition: I have another system Windows 7 in my laptop)

```
Partition table:   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    83891429    41945683+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        83891491   625141759   270625134+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        83891493   264253184    90180846    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       264253248   444614939    90180846    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       444616704   446568447      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       495398912   612583423    58592256   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       612585472   625141759     6278144   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      446570496   495396863    24413184   83  Linux
```

Comment: according to this http://listoftalisman.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/linux-how-to-use-remastersys-in-ubuntu/, the maximum filesize should not exceed 4GB, isn't that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Remastersys you can use dd, it is a command line tool mostly used to make backups
To back a Hard Disk/Partition use following command.

```
           dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk1.iso
```

If there is no enough space you can compress your backup using gzip or bzip2

Comment: Thank you for your answer,This is my parition table.If I use the command dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk1.iso,which will backup all the disk including two system windos and linux? I just want to backup my linux data,can u tell me how to do.please.

Comment: I add the Partition table in my question zone.

Comment: Another Method is to use SquashFS. You can simply install squashfs tools from Ubuntu Software Centre. Then type the command mksquashfs / /home/Lin.sfs